# Please don't teleport me

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page

The location I entered years ago was

```
Catalonia
```

but sometime between [October 3](https://web.archive.org/web/20161003132141/https://stackoverflow.com/users/1529630/oriol) and [November 8](https://web.archive.org/web/20161108114336/https://stackoverflow.com/users/1529630/oriol) you changed my location to

```
Barcelona, Catalonia, Spain
```

I didn't enter that text. Maybe I searched jobs near Barcelona for curiosity, or maybe I entered Barcelona in my private developer story if the field required a city. But in my profile I didn't say so.

Comment: Huh... I'd be curious to see if an RCA could be generated for that one...

Comment: @David What is RCA? Radio Corporation of America? Reformed Church in America? Royal College of Art?

Comment: @Oriol Root Cause Analysis

Comment: I see "Catalonia" in your profile right now. Maybe it's a geolocation issue? Can you try with a different browser maybe?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I changed it back when I noticed.

Comment: Might want to screen capture it next time. And then draw a red freehand circle around it.

Comment: http://imgsharer.eu/tinygrab/90470065fbbe7bec9e512a0d92ac2963.png There you go, @Machavity

Comment: @Farkie [Freehand circles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/244695). Get with the program! :P

Comment: http://imgsharer.eu/tinygrab/beea51f92fd1632e3cb3359eb556c579.png

Comment: Out of curiosity... did the teleport from wherever you are in Catalonia to Barcelona give you Gaudy visions... Or the usual tingle of deconstruction?

Comment: @Bruce0 They teleported me to Sagrada Família, so I had gaudy visions of Gaudí's building.

Comment: @Oriol Republica Catalana Autonoma ;)?

Comment: ... take your upvote, damn you and your Trekky-ish title

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This was likely changed around October 11 when the great developer story import was ongoing. By default, the location field in the developer story becomes linked to your main profile's location. Changing it in one place also changes it in the other. You can turn off this synchronization by editing your developer story and clicking in the location field. A checkbox will appear with it:

[image: Synchronize with your profile]

Past that, there's nothing else we can really do. The import already happened, and we're not going to do *another* import over all the data. The only way it could be changed in the future is if you continued editing without deselecting that checkbox.

Comment: I didn't have that "Synchronize with your profile" checkbox. I only got this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxA9z.png. It was hidden by `.privacy-wrapper .privacy-checkbox`. I displayed it with my devtools, unchecked it, and saved. Now I can see the checkbox.

Comment: @Oriol Hmm, there must be some trigger for it other than just clicking in the box. You must have to start editing it or something. That's strange.

Comment: If I check it back, then it disappears again.

Comment: So for next time, please ensure that the SE engineers take care **not** to modify our profiles without opt-in.

Comment: @Oriol I checked with the devs and this did happen due to the Developer Story import. We had to make a few decisions on what to do with the Careers data to make sure that we didn't dispose of valid data from Careers when we did the mass import. One of them was deciding what to do with location in the profile vs careers.