# Can moderators or users with high reputation edit my Stack Overflow profile?

Tags: discussion, support, edits, moderation

I updated the "About Me" section in my user profile on Stack Overflow months ago, and I said something about how I have my Bachelors Degree in Applied Mathematics from California State University, Chico. Now just a few minutes ago I decided to look at my own profile to see if there was anything I needed to change  (I've been looking for employment), and the description of the school was changed to "University of California, Chico" (which doesn't exist). This isn't some simple mistake I would make because I was tired, or not paying attention! Anyone familiar with the California education system definitely knows the difference between CSU and UC. Trust me, if I had a degree from a UC school - I probably wouldn't even have to look for a job on Stack Overflow.

I just want to know if this is something moderators are even allowed to edit? Unless it's something offensive, personal details like this shouldn't be edited except by the user. Something like this could be damaging. It makes me look stupid if I don't even know what university I received my degree from (or it looks like I'm a phoney because that school doesn't even exist).

Does anybody have any idea about this type of thing? Has it happened before? Is it even allowed?

Comment: Do you use Developer Story? It might be the same problem as this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340520

Comment: @approxiblue - Yes I do! Thank you for the valuable information!

Comment: One thing though: users with high reputation cannot edit other users profiles. Moderators can and so can CM's but their actions are logged.

Comment: On MSE: [What can an elected moderator do to my profile?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/267348)

Comment: Occam's razor - Who else has access to your laptop? Could they have edited (probably as a prank) it if your StackExchange sites are already logged in through the Remember me feature?

Comment: @Pierce: **1.** Do you have any automatic spell checking in your web browser that could have changed words without you noticing? This kind of thing happens in mobile phone conversations all the time. **2.** Have you considered that your account might have been hacked? If someone else has your login credentials, they can change your profile and make it look as if you were the one editing. Perhaps change your password.

Answer (score 49):

Only you, elected moderators, and employees can edit your About Me section. Any such access is logged.

I only see 2 entries in your history, for Oct 6 '16, and today (about 15 minutes before you posted your question). In both cases you were the editor. So if something changed, it was something that wasn't using the normal channels available to moderators or employees, as no log entry exists for it.

Moderators and employees would only edit an About Me to remove content that violates the terms of service. Editing to make changes like you describe would be far outside our mandate.

I don't think the profile was ever altered outside of those two entries however. Using the Internet Archive, I can access the earliest copy of your profile *with* the About Me filled in, from [October 11 '16](https://web.archive.org/web/20161011024524/https://stackoverflow.com/users/5378116/pierce), so 5 days after you edited. That version contains the error, so it *looks* as if you were the source of the mistake:

[image: Copy of Pierce's profile from the internet archive dated 2016-10-11]

<s>There is also a chance that [this issue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340520/please-dont-teleport-me) caused the change, as the Developer Story import took place around that time too. I don't know if that change affects About Me data, my impression is that it only affected the location field. Even if this was the case, how that would then produce an invalid non-existing University is not clear to me, I'll ping the CMs.</s> Bluefeet [confirmed this wasn't a Dev Story import issue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341587/can-moderators-or-users-with-high-reputation-edit-my-stack-overflow-profile/341592#comment433369_341592).

Comment: This is potentially very serious. In the UK you can find yourself facing criminal charges if you misrepresent academic qualifications to an employer.

Comment: @MalcolmMcLean: the 'about me' is not presented to employers. Their [Developer Story](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/5378116) which *is*, is correct.

Comment: @MalcolmMcLean: and to be convicted, a prosecutor would have to prove there was an intent to deceive. A misspelling of a university name such that it forms a *non-existing entity*, is never going to stand up in criminal case.

Comment: I know. Justice will almost certainly prevail. But the consequences could still be serious. Integrity of personal profiles is not something to take lightly.

Comment: I appreciate everyone's insight. I just can't fathom any way I would possibly end up mis-typing my own university. This is a town I've lived in most my life, and both my parents are still to this day professors at CSU, Chico. I could differentiate the two university systems in my sleep. I suppose there is always a small chance that something went horribly wrong in my brain that day and I mis-represented my alma mater, but the likelihood is almost nonexistent. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Pierce - given what you describe of your situation (parents at CSU, Chico) and the nature of the error (referencing Chico in error), I'd say the error is more likely yours.   There is a greater likelihood that "Chico" somehow made its way from a brain-fart to your fingers to your keyboard (i.e. a PEBKAC-related error) rather than some other mysterious process or person producing that exact effect.

Comment: @Peter But the error wasn't mentioning Chico, it was saying "University of California" rather than "California State University." OP was saying that he is extremely familiar with the correct name of the university and the distinction between UC and CSU.

Comment: @MalcolmMcLean only if you _intentionally_ misrepresent yourself with the specific purpose of gain for yourself or another individual. The more likely reality is that you would just be dismissed and that would be the end of it.

Comment: This was not a result of the Developer Story import.

Comment: @Pierce  Maybe you were concentrating so hard on the difference between CSU and UC that you typed out the latter unconsciously simply because you were so intensely focused on it.

Comment: Were you using any voice recognition software?

Comment: @J.. - how many times have we all gone back and read something we've written and gone, "What the..?". This seems a likely explanation. Either that or one of the Illuminati has gotten into SO and is changing things around. Again. (*sigh*) I'll ask at the next meeting...

Comment: `Any such access is logged.` Where is it logged? Is it accessible to the users themselves?

Comment: @ZN13: in a moderator-only account log section. No, users can't access that.